# how do I resolve this issue with Oracle?

Tags: oracle, triggers

```
ORA-00001: unique constraint (WEBAPP.LOGIN_LOCKOUT_LOG_INSTANCE_PK) violated
ORA-06512: at "WEBAPP.AFTER_UPDATE_LOCKOUT_STATUS", line 2
ORA-04088: error during execution of trigger 'WEBAPP.AFTER_UPDATE_LOCKOUT_STATUS'
ORA-06512: at "WEBAPP.UPDATE_USER_LOCK_STATUS", line 7
ORA-06512: at line 8
```

How do I fix it?

```
create or replace trigger WEBAPP.AFTER_UPDATE_LOCKOUT_STATUS
AFTER UPDATE
OF ACCOUNT_LOCKED
ON WEBAPP.EMPLOYEE 
REFERENCING NEW AS NEW OLD AS OLD
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
INSERT INTO WEBAPP.LOGIN_LOCKOUT_LOG (LOCKOUT_LOG_INSTANCE, EMPLOYEE_NUMBER, LOCKOUT_DATE_TIME, LOCKOUT_FLAG)
VALUES
(LOCKOUT_LOG_INSTANCE.NEXTVAL,:OLD.EMPLOYEE_NUMBER, SYSDATE, :NEW.ACCOUNT_LOCKED);
END;
```

Answer (score 0):

The error message says it all:

> ```
> ORA-00001: unique constraint (WEBAPP.LOGIN_LOCKOUT_LOG_INSTANCE_PK) violated
> ```

You have a unique constraint named `LOGIN_LOCKOUT_LOG_INSTANCE_PK` in the `WEBAPP` schema that has been violated by trying to insert a duplicate value into the table.

> How do I fix it?

Your trigger uses the statement:

```sql
INSERT INTO WEBAPP.LOGIN_LOCKOUT_LOG (LOCKOUT_LOG_INSTANCE, EMPLOYEE_NUMBER, LOCKOUT_DATE_TIME, LOCKOUT_FLAG)
VALUES
(LOCKOUT_LOG_INSTANCE.NEXTVAL,:OLD.EMPLOYEE_NUMBER, SYSDATE, :NEW.ACCOUNT_LOCKED);
```

I am assuming that you have a sequence named `LOCKOUT_LOG_INSTANCE` which is why you are getting the `NEXTVAL` (otherwise you code doesn't make sense). If that is so, then you need to look at why you are getting duplicate values?

- Does your application have something else that inserts values into the `WEBAPP.LOGIN_LOCKOUT_LOG`? If so, check that all the other places that insert into the table are also using the sequence.
- Has anyone recreated the sequence? Check that the next value from the sequence is greater than the maximum value of the primary key column.

Comment: how do I increment the values or check? the code was not written by me. It was there from a long time ago. I am not too familiar with Oracle Procedures.